# How we can get the customer id from the customer context

Tags: magento2

I need to know is there a way to get the customer id from the customer context

```
$loginObjectManager= \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$httpContext = $loginObjectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
$isLoggedIn = $httpContext ->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
```

The above code is to check if the user is login. I tried getting it with session as well but it returns null `'Magento\Customer\Model\Session'`

Comment: OK I have resolved it in this way using the object manager

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
 $customerSession = $objectManager->create("Magento\Customer\Model\Session");
 echo $customerSession->getCustomerId();

But I still need to know how we can do it through the http customer context

Comment: You can't get it through `\Magento\Customer\Model\Context` as it just contain 2 constant that does not include customer id